# How to promote a different player as club president?

Tags: test-drive-unlimited-2

How, exactly, do you promote a different player to President? I started a club but, unfortunately, I'm the player with the lowest activity in the club, and I would like to promote the guy with the highest activity to President. I read in a [post](http://forums.testdriveunlimited2.com/showpost.php?p=305876&postcount=13) by one of the game masters that it's possible, but there doesn't seem to be any indication on how exactly one can do it. If I go to the club hierarchy screen, I can't demote myself or promote a different player past "Executive".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't think there's an easy way to do this. I haven't tried myself, but I believe you need to demote everyone below Executive except for the person you want to be the new President, then quit the club and have them re-invite you. The one Executive should get appointed to take over as President when you quit, and they can promote you to whatever rank you want after you re-join. There's a thread that discusses this [on the TDU2 forums](http://forums.testdriveunlimited2.com/showthread.php?t=46921) and seems to indicate that this works.